# Is it possible to integrate python with CSS, Javascript, and HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, web

I have a frontend web application built with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. I would like to incorporate the output of a Python script into my frontend without using a server or a full backend solution.

The Python script is a simple neural network, and I want to display its output in the frontend, such as showing the result as a header or plotting a graph generated by the script.

I have already tried printing the output to the console from the Python script, but I need assistance with transferring that output to the frontend.

Is it possible to achieve this without a server? I am open to suggestions and starting with a simpler solution, like plotting a graph generated by the Python script in the frontend.

I appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to accomplish this. Thank you!

I have looked into Django but I feel as if that seems too complex and more server focused for the simple task I require.

! ANSWERED ! It only lets me accept one answer but I would say that both the streamlit and the Wasm Answers are acceptable.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to run Python model in the front-end but maybe look into **Tensorflow.js** that can run in the browser via Node.js. Maybe you'll be able to incorporate it into the front-end, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to incorporate the output of a Python script into your frontend without using a server or a full backend solution, you have a few options available. One approach is to use a technique called "WebAssembly" (Wasm) to run the Python script directly in the browser.
Emscripten: https://emscripten.org/
Pyodide: https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide

Comment: Along these lines there is also [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/) that uses pyodide to underly the framework. [Demos here](https://pyscript.net/examples/). Because it is using Pyodide, it is limited by the abilities and packages that Pyodide supports, which is still developing at a fast pace.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are trying to make a web application with no backend.
javascript is your only hope, if there is no backend.
it is not possible to integrate python with CSS, Javascript, and HTML without a backend.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the same problem we solved by using the python package [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/). Streamlit is a Python package that can be installed using `pip install streamlit`. You run your scripts from command line using `streamlit run <python-scipt>`.
You can also deploy streamlit on a server to serve your python scripts e.g. within a company network.